# How do I iterate over a collection, but segment results by date?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So I have a series of `@events`, currently defined in the controller like so:

```
@events = current_user.events.order(created_at: :desc)
```

But, in my view, I want to be able to display the events in different categories, but all sorted by the day on which it was created. E.g., something like this:

**Today**

- Event 1
- Event 2
- Event 3

**Yesterday**

- Event 1
- Event 2
- Event 3

**July 27**

- Event 1
- Event 2
- Event 3

**July 26**

- Event 1
- Event 2
- Event 3

Naturally, I would like to have the name of the days displayed dynamically (i.e. today should always show `Today`, so I guess using Rails days helper is fine.

But I would also like for it to switch over to the regular Date once say 2 or 3 days have passed.

What's the most elegant way to approach this? Ideally, it would be awesome if I could simply modify the `@events` instance variable to accommodate this, and then just create some helpers in the view.

But what would that look like, both the `@events` modification and the helpers.

Comment: can you group by created date.? and order them.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get grouped records from the database:

```
@grouped_events = @events.group_by { |e| e.created_at.to_date }
```

This will give you a hash with dates as keys, and arrays of events as values.

Comment: This will order them by date created, not necessarily the date of the event.

Comment: From the question: "But, in my view, I want to be able to display the events in different categories, but all sorted by the day on which it was created."

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to loop through the events and check if the date of the event differs from the last event.  If it is different display the header of today/yesterday/date then display the event, otherwise just show the event and reset the date check.

```
@events = current_user.events.order(created_at: :desc)
cur_date = nil
@events.each do |event|
  if cur_date != event.created_at
    #Logic to display Today/Yesterday/Date
  end
  cur_date = event.created_at
  #Logic here to display event
end
```